# Label an edge above and below

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, overleaf

I want to be able to label an edge with a part of the label above it and the other part below it like in the following example :

[image]

For the moment I have this solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[text=black]
  \node [draw, ] (a) at (0,0) {a};
  \node [draw, below left=4 of a] (b) {b};
  \draw[->] (a) to[bend left] node[midway, sloped, above]{to} node[midway, sloped, below]{b} (b.east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Where I create tWo midway nodes, one above the edge, the other one below it but I wanted to know if there is a simpler solution.

---

[EDIT]
@AndréC solutions gives the following result on **Overleaf**:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need two nodes for this, one with `align=center` is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[text=black]
  \path (0,0) node [draw] (a) {a}
  node[draw, below left=4 of a] (b) {b};
  \draw[->] (a) to[bend left] node[sloped, align=center]{to\\
  b} (b.east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you have placed the nodes between the coordinates, they are automatically placed in the middle of the path and therefore it is useless to ask for it expressly with `midway`.

For placement, there is the `auto=left` option that automatically places to the **left** of the path and by adding `swap`, it places it to the **right**.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[text=black,auto=left]
  \node [draw, ] (a) at (0,0) {a};
  \node [draw, below left=4 of a] (b) {b};
  \draw[->] (a) to[bend left] node[sloped]{to} node[sloped,swap]{b} (b.east) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the midway tip, didn't know it worked like this. Anyway, this solution looks like mine except that it doesn't follow the edge (the text is horizontal) and if I had "sloped" to it the result looks bad. But I'm glad I learned about this "auto" option which will help me when placing multiple nodes and not having to think about above, below, left or right.

Comment: With your new edit, my result is very strange. I'll add it to my question to show you what I have.

Comment: Have you recompiled? I've updated again.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question with the result it gives me.

Comment: Your edition is not visible, there is a bug.

Comment: I don't understand what's happening. If I refresh the page, I can see the images, if I refresh it again, they disappear.

Comment: I don't see anything, erase this edition, then do it again.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that I don't have enough reputation but on my side I can see the images, now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95626/discussion-between-andrec-and-lhooq).