# Aligning diagram with arrows

Tags: arrays, alignment

I want to draw a diagram with rightarrow and downarrow.

So first I tried:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
M_n&(D) \overset{\alpha'}&\longrightarrow M_n&(R)\\
\det &\downarrow & &\downarrow \det\\
&D \overset{\alpha}&\longrightarrow &R
\end{alignat*}
```

Then it gives me:

[image]

But the rightarrow with alpha aligned at the left.

The next thing I did:

```
\begin{equation*}
\arraycolsep=1pt\def\arraystretch{1}
\begin{array}{cccccc}
& &M_n(D)\quad &\overset{\alpha'}\longrightarrow\quad &M_n(R) &\\
&\det &\downarrow &\quad &\downarrow &\det\\
& &D &\overset{\alpha}\longrightarrow &R &
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

This gives me:

[image]

It looks better, but what I really want is that first downarrow looks the same as the second downarrow, that is, it starts from between 'n' and '('. Also the rightarrows do not look like aligned at all.

What should I do?

Comment: Your second code works perfectly. Everything is perfectly aligned. Except under **Overleaf** which has a real problem since there has already been a case where the compilation result with Overleaf is not the same as on his own computer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498353/138900
you should report this malfunction to the Overleaf team.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! I recommend `tikz-cd` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em,row sep=3em]
M_n(D) \arrow[r,"\alpha'"] \arrow[d,"\det"]  & M_n(R)\arrow[d,"\det"]\\
D \arrow[r,"\alpha"] &R 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If needed, you can make `det` larger. (The font sizes of the `\alpha`s can be increased in the same way.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=3em,row sep=3em]
M_n(D) \arrow[r,"\alpha'"] \arrow[d,"\displaystyle\det"]  & M_n(R)\arrow[d,"\displaystyle\det"]\\
D \arrow[r,"\alpha"] &R 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks great!

Comment: @Xaviere You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Considering that I absolutely agree with the very good user @marmot, I add another code using `xy` package. Look closely at the almost similar comparison between `tikz-cd` and `xy`, except for the tips of the arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=3pc@C=3pc{
M_n(D) \ar[r]^{\alpha'} \ar[d]^{\det} & M_n(R) \ar[d]^{\det}\\
D \ar[r]^{\alpha} & R\\
}
\end{document}
```

If you add only `cmtip`, you can obtain the same tips of `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}%%%%%%%% <---------add only cmtip
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=3pc@C=3pc{
M_n(D) \ar[r]^{\alpha'} \ar[d]^{\det} & M_n(R) \ar[d]^{\det}\\
D\ar[r]^{\alpha} & R\\
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, I still like drawing with pure TikZ, without using packages as `tikzcd`, `xy`, even without using TikZ's library `positioning`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
(0,0) node (MD) {$M_n(D)$}
+(0:3) node (MR) {$M_n(R)$}
++(-90:2) node (D) {$D$}
+(0:3) node (R) {$R$};

\draw[->] (MD)--(MR) node[midway,above]{$\alpha'$};
\draw[->] (D)--(R) node[midway,above]{$\alpha$};
\draw[->] (MD)--(D) node[midway,right]{$\rm det$};
\draw[->] (MR)--(R) node[midway,right]{$\rm det$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]